# Deriving expression for the DTFT of a rectangular window

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, lowpass-filter, window-functions, dtft

[image]

Looking at the picture above, how did the author get from point A) to B)?

**My Approach**: Multiply A) by $e^{j\omega/2}/e^{j\omega/2}$. Now I am stuck with simplying the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mistake in the denominator of B. This is the way it should be done:

$$\begin{align}R(\omega)&=\frac{1-e^{-j\omega (M+1)}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\\&=\frac{e^{-j\omega(M+1)/2}}{e^{-j\omega/2}}\cdot\frac{e^{j\omega(M+1)/2}-e^{-j\omega(M+1)/2}}{e^{j\omega/2}-e^{-j\omega/2}}\\&=e^{-j\omega M/2}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{M+1}{2}\omega\right)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\end{align}$$